# How can I specify dynamic value in object literal assignment?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I got after running my code through JSLint:

Expected ':' and instead saw '+'. '"Book":"'+bookname+'"' line 3 column 23

Unexpected trailing space. '"Book":"'+bookname+'"'

I want to specify in a JSON string to find results if they contain the value of "bookid" in the "Book" column (cf. lines 1-4 below).

I understand that there are errors with the syntax. It was working great until I decided I needed to use a value from local storage. I am unsure of how to properly call a regular variable in this kind of query. What is wrong?

```
var bookname = localStorage.getItem('bookid');

var whereObject = {
    "$and": [{
        '"Book":"'+bookname + '"'
    }
    }, {
        "$or": [{
            "calf_id": {
                "$regex": "^" + value,
                "$options": "i"
            }
        }, {
            "cow_id": {
                "$regex": "^" + value,
                "$options": "i"
            }
        }, {
            "Sire": {
                "$regex": "^" + value,
                "$options": "i"
            }
        }, {
            "Color": {
                "$regex": "^" + value,
                "$options": "i"
            }
        }]
    }]
    };

return JSON.stringify(whereObject);
```

`value` is the value that is in the search bar.

I tried to change it using the advice given me, but then it just produces more warnings, similar to the ones I already have.

I basically need to know what the proper way to use a previously defined variable in a query. I don't know the proper syntax and haven't been able to find anything only

Answer (score 1):

```
'"Book":"'+bookname + '"'
```

why are you using `'`'s? i'm not sure why you are doing that.
in json, you should end the string before the `:` charachter. and after the `:` you type the value for the `Book`.

```
"KEY":"VALUE"
```

if value of `Book` is a string:

```
"Book" : "hello this is string"
```

if the value of `Book` is a variable:

```
"Book": bookname
```

if you want your `Book` to have a value of the `bookname` variable but enclosed in quotes, you do

```
"Book": "'" + bookname + "'"
```

if you look carefully and count the number of { and }'s in your json you see the number is not even! which means you have a mistake matching those.
here is the valid json without syntax error:

```
{
  "$and": [


       {
         "Book":"bookname"
       },


       {
         "$or": [
             {"calf_id": {"$regex":"^" + value,"$options": "i"}},
             {"cow_id":  {"$regex":"^" + value,"$options": "i"}},
             {"Sire":    {"$regex":"^" + value,"$options": "i"}},
             {"Color":   {"$regex":"^" + value,"$options": "i"}}
         ]
       }


  ]
}
```

Comment: so if `bookname` contains the value `an introduction to programming` , after the last line of the post it will contain the value `'an introduction to programming'`

Comment: when I change the code to either of the last two examples you showed me, JSLint said.... Expected ']' and instead saw '}'.
    `}, {`. When I go try to fix it based on their suggestion, more errors appear.

Comment: well that's a good thing, it means you solved the last error. i updated my answer and added the valid json. i don't have time to explain right now, but it's valid and you can use [jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) as a tool, too.